# Installing Ubuntu on a Dell R210 with S100 raid controller

Tags: ubuntu, installation, dell-poweredge

I recently picked up a Dell PowerEdge R210 II and would like to install Ubuntu on it.

I am getting an error when going through the install process. It seems to hang on "removing previous storage devices". The server was wiped before I got it

Here are the steps I have done:

1. Created a usb boot disk with Universal USB Installer from https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ (I have also tried Rufus 3.13).
2. I downloaded Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS and also tried 18.04 LTS. I don't think I need ARM, POWER, s390x, or Provisioning or anything like that
3. There is 1 1TB harddrive installed. I made sure the SATA settings were set to AHCI instead of RAID. Just for fun I also tried ATA.
4. Boot mode is in UEFI
5. To install I insert the USB drive and select "Install Ubuntu Server"
6. Select English as my install languange
7. Click Done for the keyboard
8. Click Done for the Network connections. It recognizes the ethernet connection
9. Done on the proxy address
10. Done on the mirror address
11. I leave the default settings for the guided storage config. "Use entire disk" and "Set up this disk as an LVM group"
12. Hit done on the storage configuration.
13. Click continue to confirm destructive action
    This screen is where the error shows up. "Removing previous storage devices" is the last message and a little popup saying there was a problems appears.

Am I on the right track? I saw other questions where people were having problems and the solutions all seemed to be to make sure RAID was off and I have made sure to do that. I also tried with RAID on and it didn't seem to make a difference. My understanding is RAID doesn't really matter if I only have 1 harddrive

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on PowerEdge R310 and I was able resolve it with UNetbootin https://unetbootin.github.io to create a USB boot disk.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
The issue occurs when ubuntu need to make disk changes.

1. Download DBAN linux image (https://dban.org)
2. Burn ISO in usb or cd or dvd
3. boot with this disk
4. Execute a Wipe in your disk(s) with this tool (it will take a while)
5. When finish, reboot and install Ubuntu... works for me.